# Using the Facebook API, not always able to create a link back to the status

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm consuming the facebook API in order to get status from pages feeds.

After parsing the raw response, I'm generating the links back to the original post on facebook like this:

```
"https://facebook.com/" + status_id
```

This works great, unless there are pages mentions in the status. In this case the url leads to a 404 error.

After some research, I found in this case, the first half of the status id, containing the user id, have the id of the mentioned page, not from the status author.

Do you know if this is intentional or a bug by Facebook API, and do you know a reliable way to generate links back tho original statuses on facebook, regardless of the status type?

Thanks!

Comment: Don’t “generate” any URLs yourself – instead, request the `permalink_url` field of the post objects.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for responding, I'll try that.

Comment: @CBroe, I added this on the fields list and worked like a charm. Sorry this not being well document, as this fields is not present here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/post/. Thanks again!